# GitHub Actions fails when NLTK "punkt" is needed

Tags: python, continuous-integration, nltk, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have written some code which needs to use NLTK's punkt. I have included `nltk` in the `requirements.txt` and in the `setup.py`. However, when I run the build of my project using GitHub actions, it fails with this error.

```
E       LookupError:   
E       **********************************************************************  
E         Resource punkt not found.  
E         Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  
E       
E         >>> import nltk  
E         >>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

What is the standard way to tell GitHub actions that it needs `'punkt'` without hard coding `nltk.download('punkt')` somewhere into the code?
Should I add a line in the `ci.yml` file, and what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I have found a way of fixing this by adding   
`echo -e "import nltk\nnltk.download('punkt')" | python3`   
to the `ci.yml` before running the tests with pytest. However, any more elegant solution is very welcome.

Comment: try to create nltk.txt file and include the `punkt`?

Comment: Also just used the `ci.yml` change that andrea proposed. Seems to be working :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ci.yml` file,  adding the `nltk.downloader` commandline after importing dependencies defined in `requirements.txt` worked for me.

```
if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
python -m nltk.downloader punkt stopwords
```

Answer (score -1):

For me this command does not work:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

but I still have a solution to this problem, that worked for me.

You have to manually download the punkt file yourself, but while writing this the site is not working but I got you covered so you can download it from here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20230206063107/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip

after downloading the file you have to go to

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\
```

If the nltk_data folder does not exist then create one and go inside the folder and create an other folder named tokenizers and extract the punkt.zip file inside the tokenizers folder.

I hope this helps